# Text based menu driven program. How can i make this program complete? I'm kind of stuck (functions, if, elif, else, while-loops, for-loops, lists)

Tags: python-3.x

**Updated**
Hi, i'm new to this community and i really need some assistance.

I've got an assignment to help a school with grading students in 5 courses every year, it also needs to print out if the student is in year 1, 2 and 3. We also need to calculate the average score by the end of each year.

The five courses are: Swedish, English, Mathematics, Programming and Computer science.

The grades consists of: IG(did not pass the course), G(lowest grade needed to pass a course), VG(second highest grade to pass a course) and MVG(highest grade to pass a course).

Summerize of assignment:
1. The teacher must be able to add students
2. Add courses to a student, add grades to students
3. Associate the grades with a score to count average score per year for each student
4. print out the teachers input to view students, courses, grades and average score per year.

What i've done this far is the following(bare in mind, i've been programming python for only a couple of days):

```
import os                           #imports operativesystem
clear = lambda: os.system("cls")    #enables clearscreen cmd

student_list = []
student_grades_list = []

def addgrade():
    clear()
    swedish = input("Enter swedish grade[IG-MVG]: ")
    english = input("Enter english grade[IG-MVG]: ")
    mathematics = input("Enter mathematics grade[IG-MVG]: ")
    programming = input("Enter programming grade[IG-MVG]: ")
    computer_science = input("Enter computer science grade[IG-MVG]: ")

    student_grades_list = [swedish, english, mathematics, programming, computer_science]
    grades_list = []

    count = 0
    score = 0

    while count < len(student_grades_list):
        grades = student_grades_list[count]
        grades_list = []

        if student_grades_list == "IG":
            score = 0
            grades_list.append(student_grades_list)

        elif student_grades_list == "G":
            score = 1
            grades_list.append(student_grades_list)

        elif student_grades_list == "VG":
            score = 3
            grades_list.append(student_grades_list)

        elif student_grades_list == "MVG":
            score = 5
            grades_list.append(student_grades_list)


        count += 1

    avgScore = sum(grades_list)/len(student_grades_list)

    if avgScore < 1:
        print("You have not passed this years course, you have an average score of: {}".format(avgScore))

    elif avgScore > 1 and avgScore < 5:
        print("Congratulations, you've passed this years course with an average score of: {}".format(avgScore))

    else:
        print("You've recieved a goldstar and you've passed this years course with an average score of: {}".format(avgScore))
    input("Press Enter to get back to the main menu")
    mainMenu()


def addcourse():
    clear()
    print("You're about to add a course to a student")
    input("Enter what course the student is taking: ")
    input("Press Enter to go back to main menu")
    mainMenu()

def addstudent():
    clear()
    print("You're about to add a student")
    input("Enter the student's full name: ")
    int(input("Enter what year the student is in: "))
    input("Press Enter to go back to main menu")
    mainMenu()

def mainMenu():
    clear()
    print("""
         ____________   **HELLO, LET ME BE YOUR SERVANT!**
        /| \  ___  / |         /
       / |  \(_O_)/  |        |o__
      |//|   |   |   |\      //
      // |    \_/    |\\\    //
     //  |           | \\\  //
    //|  |           |  \\\//
   // |  |           |   ''
  //  \  |    ___    |
 ||    \ |   |   |   |
 ||     \|___|   |___|
/  \         |   |
             |___|
 _______________________________________________
|###############################################|
|## Welcome To Claptrap School Grading System ##|
|###############################################|
|                                               |
|     1. Add a student                          |
|     2. Add courses to a student               |
|     3. Add grades to a student                |
|     4. Look up students grades                |
|     5. Quit/Exit                              |
|_______________________________________________|
          """)
    choice = input("Choose your option: ")

    if choice == "1":
        addstudent()

    elif choice == "2":
        addcourse()

    elif choice == "3":
        addgrade()

    elif choice == "4":
        lookgrade()

    elif choice == "5":
        print("Thank you for using Claptrap School Grading System!")
        exit()
    else:
        clear()
        print("Invalid option, please enter a valid option[1-5]")
        input("Press Enter to go back to the menu")
        mainMenu()

mainMenu()
```

I'm not finished defining everything but i feel like i'm on the right track now. What my teacher told me is that i must put a while loop somewhere where i call my functions. My problem at this time is that i'm not sure on where to put my loop and what's left to define for this program to work properly. If someone of you could please show me how i could finish defining just one of these functions, i would be greatful as hell:) Also, explain as short and concise as possible what you did and why.

And yes, that is one hell of a handsome Claptrap! I made him to make my project more fun and interesting, also i wanted my teacher to smile or laugh, he did both so i'm satisfied:D

This program is intended to be educational and nothing else.

Thank you beforehand!

Thanks!

Comment: It looks great so far - maybe I am missing the question in your post...

But, if you want to incorporate a `while` loop or a `for` loop in your program, you can simply add a loop around your `input` command to receive multiple grades from the terminal, add an exit condition (ex - if the user presses 'q', they can continue through the program). Then you can add another loop around your conditionals to check every element in the array that the user populated.

Does that make sense? If there was a question in your post and I missed it, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We must use while, for loop, if, elif, else and list in this assignment. I'm struggling with while and for loops and when to use them. Is there any chance you could show me a small example of how I can make use of them? I feel a bit stuck atm.